# Rasterizing TrueType fonts in Haskell

Tags: haskell, bitmap, rendering, truetype, rasterizing

I'd like to build a function that takes a given Unicode character and a given TrueType font and rasterises the corresponding glyph into a two-dimensional 1-bit-per-pixel bitmap.

Something similar to this:

```hs
rasterize :: Font -> Char -> Size -> Bitmap
rasterize font char size = ...
```

## Requirements

The `rasterize` function should:

- produce a bitmap of maximal width `w` and height `h`, such that `w <= size` and `h <= size`
- rasterize the glyph so that it completely fills the bitmap, leaving no padding.

The `Bitmap` type should support the following operations (or similar):

```hs
width  :: Bitmap -> Int
height :: Bitmap -> Int
bit    :: Bitmap -> (Int, Int) -> Bool
```

where `bit b (x, y)` should evaluate to `True` if (and only if) the bit within Bitmap `b` at index position `(x, y)` is set.

## Question

Are there any Haskell libraries that can already do this, or something similar?

## Example

Evaluating the expression `rasterize fontUtopiaStandard 'o' 64` would result in a Bitmap `b` that if rendered would look similar to the following image (viewed at 800% scale, with grid), where `(width b, height b) = (60, 64)`:

[image]

## Notes

1. I've already tried using the [stb-truetype package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/stb-truetype), but any attempts to get at the pixel data seem to cause segmentation faults, even when compiling with version of GHC (6.12) similar to the version on which the package was tested. (I can provide more details of the segfaulting code if anyone's interested.)
2. I'm aware of the existence of libraries that render TrueType fonts within an OpenGL context, but I can't see how to get access to the pixel data.

Comment: Regarding 2., you just need to render to texture to get the pixel data.